# Is there nothing to look forward to next year?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

For all its ups and downs as a year, **2017 is a prime number**. However, after midnight, the year is 2018. It is not a prime number! It is also...

- *not* a fibonacci number
- *not* a Bell number
- *not* a perfect number
- *not* a factorial
- *not* a catalan number

...and so on. The only good thing Wolfram Alpha has to say about $2018$ is that it's a divisor of $87^{18} - 1$, but I see nothing special about that.

So please help me out: **What is the best thing to toast to when 2018 arrives?**

Comment: Honestly the best thing to toast to is that WWIII will have (probably) not started (yet?)...

Comment: It is the smallest number that is not special!

Comment: $13^2+43^2=2018$

Comment: Not exactly a mathematical answer, but it's the first year when all minors will have been born in the 21st century/3rd millennium.

Comment: I think it makes 2018 being special for not being special. A parker year, maybe? ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Every natural number is the sum of four integer squares, but 2018 is:

$$2018=(6^2)^2+(5^2)^2+(3^2)^2+(2^2)^2$$ the sum of four squares of squares.

Comment: Oh, that's nice.

Answer (score 11):

Someone born that year will be having their 30 years party in $2048 = 2^{11}$ which is probably the only power-of-two any of us will live to see.

Answer (score 11):

There is exactly one non-abelian group of order $2018$ by the Sylow-Theorems. There are exactly 2018 duplicates of this here at MSE:

[Nonabelian group of order $pq $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467942/nonabelian-group-of-order-pq)

[Groups of order $pq$ are cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502186/groups-of-order-pq-are-cyclic/1502364)

[Group of order pq is not simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222853/group-of-order-pq-is-not-simple/2557807)

[Question about soluble and cyclic groups of order pq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735728/question-about-soluble-and-cyclic-groups-of-order-pq?rq=1)

$\cdots $

$\cdots$

[Non Abelian group of order pq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114735/non-abelian-group-of-order-pq)

Comment: "There are exactly 2018 duplicates of this" Citation needed :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, I should say that [Even What’s Special About This Number](https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html) has no result for the number $2018$...

Comment: Wow, speciality of $2017$ is not only being prime, I did not know that $2017$ has such speciality as being the value of $n$ with $\phi(n) = \phi(n-1)+\phi(n-2)$. I am sure in some Math Olympiad, the question "Find the value of $n$ that satisfies $\phi(n) = \phi(n-1)+\phi(n-2)$" is asked in this year :D

Comment: For a moment I thought you are talking about the number 2018!! and I wondered how in the world did somebody analyze that huge number

Comment: @Stefan4024 Well, that was unintentional....

Answer (score 5):

If there is a special name for the even numbers of the form $2p$, where $p$ is a prime number, then $2018 = 2\cdot 1009$ where $1009$ is a prime number.

The closest thing that I found is the numbers called "Safe Numbers" which is in the form of $2p+1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime

Comment: Semiprimes. :))

Comment: Oh, nice! We found something special about $2018$ then :)

Comment: So 2018 is only half as good as 2017? Still, that's something! :)

Comment: ahahah, yes that's how it could be expressed in the best way :D

Answer (score 4):

[Ramanujan-Nagell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation) is exponential Diophantine equation of the form $$2^n-7=x^2$$

When I searched for squares close to $2018$ I discovered that we have $$2018=45^2-7$$ and then I observed that $2018$ is a solution of Diophantine equation

$$2^n+2^{n-1}+...+2^5+2=x^2-7$$

for $n=10$ and $x=45$, which is one of myriad of possible generalizations of Ramanujan-Nagell equation.

Answer (score 2):

We can look forward to less evil, at least. 2017 is a very evil number.  I have two proofs of this.

1. Note that 5 is the number of Satan and that "derangement" is a nasty word.  How many derangements are there of 5?  44.  So 44 is evil compounded.  Also note that we had this nice pattern: 3, 5, 7, ... where all the odds were prime. What screwed it up?  9.  Evil, evil 9.  Is it any wonder that Christ died "at the 9th hour?"   So we have 9 and 44, already evil compounded.  Let's re-compound them by squaring and re-re-compound them by adding the results:

$$9^2+44^2 = 2017.$$

Chilling, no?  There's more"

2. We know that gambling is evil and in craps the phrase is "7, 11 or doubles."
   To get "doubles" let's take 7 twice: 7, 7, 11.  There's a multi-set of evil.  Let's super-compound them by cubing (and note that dice are cubes!) and add:

$$7^3+7^3 + 11^3 = 2017.$$

Thankfully, there are only a few hours left in this horrible year.  Let's hope we make it to 2018.

Comment: Can't wait to see what scary stuff you come up with for Halloween...
This gave me a good laugh!